# Clone in source tree link

Tags: bitbucket

On the bit bucket repositories there is a "Clone in SourceTree" link. does anybody know how this works as I would like to add it to and application im working on.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlassian SourceTree is a free Git and Mercurial client for Mac and Windows, so it's a link to download and open the repo with their software on your computer

Comment: I understand this but as the link is in the browser one would think this can be triggered by visiting a certain type of url, similar to how magnet link urls work.

Comment: The custom URI scheme  used by atlassian is like this : sourcetree://cloneRepo/https://user@bitbucket.org/other/project. To handle it in your own app you can look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx