# Can't create new branch.Unknown protocol

Tags: git, bitbucket

I try to create a new branch on BitBucket , when I press "checkOut source tree" opera give me following message '' (screens are below ). What I should do?
[image: Create branch]

[image: Give a name to branch]

[image]

[image: Unknown protocol]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Opera is your default browser, and SourceTree might not have [registered itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) as a magnet link (see [those comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28165232/6309)).
See [this thread](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1876909/magnet-links-in-windows-10/p1)

> Opera itself doesn't handle magnet links

Try switching to a different browser by default and see if the issue persists.

A manual workaround would be to open SourceTree manually, and checkout the branch from there.